# What is unclear about this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Yesterday I saw [a question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/15427/how-do-i-schedule-12-teams-in-a-championship-where-3-4-teams-play-at-the-same-ti) that I commented with a few clarification questions, just to make sure I understood it correctly. Which was confirmed by the OP. But when I woke up this morning, the question was put on hold for being unclear. Even though the original question was far from perfect, I couldn't see it so unclear as to put it on hold. Was it because people here are so used to a game has to be between exactly 2 teams that they could not understand that games between 3 or 4 teams is possible in some circumstances? I must say I think the question is not only quite clear, it is contentwise a very good question.

I had to put my answer in a comment, since the question is on hold. The question is edited 7 hours ago, but still on hold.

Comment: I reopened to let your answer be posted (and accepted) as the question has been clarified (unclear votes do not go away upon editing).

Comment: The person asked for a way to run multiple rounds using an elimination bracket on >2 teams per match. This is an obviously unclear (in fact, basically impossible) thing to ask for, and the question was too broad to clarify on its face. I pointed out both of these things in comments. Which I presume you have read. Then it was edited to make it more clear as the edit history reflects. Which I presume you also read. Are those presumptions incorrect?

Comment: I read those comments and the original queation. And I could not agree with you. Even from the original question it was quite clear what OP wanted. I assume you read my comment and OPs response that I was spot on.